# Broadcast Receiver not working after reboot

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have an broadcast receiver registered in the manifest for intercepting calls, like this:

```
    <receiver android:name="CallTracker">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.PHONE_STATE" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Everything works fine and the receiver gets called.
But after I restart the device or my AVD, the receiver doesn't get called anymore.

What do I have to do in order to get my broadcast receiver to work after reboot, too?
Do I need PackageManager for that?
I like the registration in the manifest, since the application doesn't have to be active in order for the app to intercept the call.

Comment: It looks like the problem is not with the receiver, but someplace else.

Comment: do u solve the problem of this issue.if yes,then let me know also.I m searching of it. @Cristian gruita

Comment: I'd like to add that with the changes made to Intents in Android 8.0 Oreo (and up) the PHONE_STATE intent can still be registered implicitly in the Manifest, BUT the Intents can be delayed by quite a bit, especially shortly after reboot when the system is still busy delivering lots of other intents.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You need to add this action to your intent-filter.

`<action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />`

Comment: This answer is not correct imho, the mentioned event ALWAYS fires after boot andhas nothing to do with the phone state.

Answer (score 0):

*I know that this question is quite old but in my opinion still relevant. Since the currently accepted answer is wrong and the comment by [user1806772](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1806772/user1806772) was the correct answer for me, I provide it as a new answer to the question:*

It probably **does** work. But directly after reboot it can take a really long time (up to multiple minutes) until the intent is delivered. Some minutes after the reboot it should work fast again.