# Android - Unable to understand how a service can be run even after a reboot

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

Someone (member "buptcoder") helped me to solve a problem I had, very quickly and nicely. I am glad I found a community here. Thanks to all of you.

I have read a lot of web pages talking "starting a service at boot time" but I still have a question in my mind.

Here is the code I already have : 
I click on a button (in an Activity) which runs a service, which register a BroadcastReceiver (SMS_RECEIVED). When I click on the back button (Google Android button), the service (and the BroadcastReceiver) is still active. Good.

Here is what I want : 
I want that service (which has been activated by the button) to auto-restart even if the user reboot the phone. The activation of the service is dynamic and I don't want it to run if the user did not press the button.

I know I should use action BOOT_COMPLETED but I can't understand how we can do it exactly.

If anyone can understand what I wrote and help me out :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned: `I know I should use action BOOT_COMPLETED but I can't understand how we can do it exactly.`

You want to know How to can use the `BOOT_COMPLETED` action? To use that you need to make some change in your `Manifest` file. Where you've specified your receiver in manifest, you can add an action in the `<intent-filter>` tag. Something as follows:

```
<receiver android:name=".Receiver" >
     <intent-filter> 
         <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>  
         ....
     </intent-filter>  
</receiver>
```

Inside the `OnReceive` function of your Broadcast Receiver, you can do whatever action you want to do when `BOOT_COMPLETE` is received. Something like:

```
//Inside your BroadCast Receiver: 
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction()!= null){
        if( intent.getAction().equals("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED") ){
            // Do something here 
        } 
    }
}
```

You also might need to add this permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Hope this helps else please comment.

Answer (score 0):

You are welcome :).  Shobhit Puri has asked your question well. I want to add some for your question.
If you just want to monitor the SMS, you even don't have to write a service. Just write a receiver, and state it in your Androidmanifest.xml, the receiver will work well even if user reboot the device:

```
<receiver android:name=".YourSmsReceiver" >
 <intent-filter> 
     <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"/>  
     ....
 </intent-filter>  
</receiver>

   //Inside your YourSmsReceiver 
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction()!= null){
        if( intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED") ){
            // Handle SMS here 
        } 
    }
}
```

Comment: Just adding to it, I think if you want the receiver to work even after reboot, you need to include BOOT_COMPLETED. There are many threads on this. Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6878816/broadcastreceiver-not-working-after-boot-completed) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5082735/broadcast-receiver-not-working-after-reboot).

Comment: Thank you both of you. Your answers solve a part of my problem. Indeed, I mentioned that I want Android to know if the user pressed the button (activate service). If not, I don't want Android to start my service at boot time. This is a dynamic registration. I think that if I hard code <action> in manifest file it won't be dynamic. Maybe I should add the action (BOOT_COMPLETED) dynamicly through addAction like I did with  SMS_RECEIVED. (To buptcoder : I will have more than one service. As I wrote in my previous message, button starts a services which register a broadcast receiver). Thanks.